# Why does Mathematica struggle with solving this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

Consider the evaluation of the following expression

```
In[20]:= Reduce[ 1000 * 1.0609^t == 1500, t]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[20]:= Reduce::ratnz: Reduce was unable to
> solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by
> solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>
> ```

```
Out[20]= C[1] ∈ Integers && 
  t == -16.9154 (-0.405465 + (0. + 6.28319 I) C[1])
```

I was expecting just `6.858618708478822` as the solution.

Comment: Try `Reduce[1000*1.0609^t == 1500, t, Reals]`. You still get an error - which you get with `NSolve` as well, but you get the right result. `FindRoot` is better with numerical results if you kinda know where to search (the case here).

Comment: Yes, you get the result but the error looks scary.  I don't understand why 'Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients'  Does anyone have any insight

Comment: I think Reduce is close to giving you the correct answer because -16.9154*-0.405465=6.85862, but for some reason it can't get rid of the complex value (0+2PiI).  I would report this to Wolfram as a bug.

Comment: Will do, thank you.

Comment: Difficult to say exactly what the difficulty was, but in *Mathematica*'s numerical model, machine-precision numbers are considered not to be exact quantities. This makes it difficult to decide if two values are equal, or whether something is exactly zero or not if machine numbers are involved. The solution it finds for this problem is to convert the machine-precision values into rationals, which are treated as exact. Strictly speaking, machine precision numbers *are* rationals, so you can do this yourself if you wish using `SetPrecision[..., Infinity]`, which will avoid the message.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: Actually, I see your point.  I suppose I was incorrectly expecting the same answer as NSolve provides, but the message from Reduce is pretty clear.

Comment: @DavidSkulsky the rounding is not perfect but `Reduce` is giving an answer that is very close to `t == -(((2*I)*Pi*C[1] - Log[3/2])/(-52*Log[2] + Log[4777868844677359]))`, which seems to produce exactly 1500 when substituted into the original equation for `C[1]` any integer. Can we remove the [bugs] tag?

Comment: Seems like a good idea.

Comment: Don't mistake messages with errors

Comment: @OleksandrR., more intuitively, perhaps, the result from `Reduce` is equivalent to `t == (Log[1500/1000] + 2 Pi I C[1]) / Log[1.0609]`

Comment: @SimonWoods yes, that's probably a better way to write it. I just wanted to be clear that the machine number 1.0609, represented as a rational, is actually equal to 4777868844677359/4503599627370496 rather than 10609/10000.

Comment: @OleksandrR., ah I see. Sorry, I misunderstood the point you were making.

Answer (score 15):

If you re-express your problem in terms of reals:

```
Reduce[1000. 1.0609^t == 1500., t, Reals]
```

you will get

> Reduce::ratnz: Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.
>
> t == 6.85862

*Mathematica* is not "struggling" with your equation. The message is simply FYI -- to tell you that, for this equation, it prefers to work with exact quantities rather than inexact quantities (reals). If you find the message annoying, you can turn it off:

```
Quiet@Reduce[1000. 1.0609^t == 1500., t, Reals]
```

> t == 6.85862

Comment: I would be wary of dismissing the message so easily. It is not produced with, for example, `Reduce[{9.2 x + 3.1 y == 4.7, 2.8 x - 7.1 y == 6.0}, {x, y}]`. As I mentioned in my comment above, I believe it indicates that difficulties were encountered in deciding conclusively whether two quantities were equal given the presence of inexact numbers. The fact that `Reduce` had to resort to solving a *related* problem, rather than the one actually posed to it, is presumably not something that one would usually wish to disregard.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I did intend to suggest the message _should_ be ignored, but I thought that the OP ought to be made aware that it _could_ be suppressed.

Comment: I know that you can suppress messages.  The message does not say Reduce *prefers* to work with exact quantities, it says *unable*.  This implies, to me at least, that there is an issue or, put another way, that Mathematica has struggled.

Comment: I was sufficiently interested to blog about this. http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=4813 if anyone is interested.

Comment: @WalkingRandomly In your blog you seem that suggest that the double precision's inability to express 1.0609 exactly causes the problem... But solving 1.75^t = 1.5 in Mathematica still yields the warning message, while both 1.75 and 1.5 can be expressed exactly in double precision.

Comment: This may be a weird question, but is it possible to know what is the "corresponding exact system" that Mathematica is using to find the solutions?

Comment: @LauraK. Not weird. It is most likely transforming the `Reduce` expression into `Reduce[1000 Rationalize[1.0609]^t == 1500, t, Reals] // N` or something very like that.

Comment: Thank you, @m_goldberg!

Answer (score 12):

As a workaround, you could always solve the equation symbolically, then replace the symbols with your constants:

```
Reduce[a*b^t == c, t] /. {a -> 1000, b -> 1.0609, c -> 1500}
```

Result:

```
C[1] ∈ Integers && t == 16.9154 (2 I π C[1] + Log[3/2])
```

And `Simplify[%]` returns:

```
C[1] ∈ Integers && t == 6.85862 + (0. + 106.283 I) C[1]
```

Comment: This seems to be what the message is telling you MMA is doing. If the problem was the message, `Quiet` seems a simpler way to achieve the same

Comment: @Rojo this is not really the same thing. I personally prefer nikie's approach: consider for instance arbitrary precision numbers for which you *also* care about their uncertainty. The answers you get by letting `Reduce` handle things by itself are rather different to those obtained by substituting into the exact solution.

Answer (score 8):

```
N@Reduce[Rationalize[1000 1.0609^t == 1500, 0], t, Reals]
```

Result (with no errors/warnings thrown):

```
t == 6.85862
```

`Rationalize[#, 0]` will generate a rational version of all numbers in an expression within machine precision. Note that if you remove the `N@` you can see the analytical solution:

```
t == (Log[2] - Log[3])/(2 (2 Log[2] + 2 Log[5] - Log[103]))
```

For fun, I added a bunch of random numbers to the expression, and Mathematica handles it like a champ:

```
Reduce[Rationalize[1000 1.0609916516846514894109^t == 1500, 0], t, Reals]

t == (Log[2] - Log[3])/
      (4 Log[2] + 2 Log[3] + Log[11] + Log[127] +
       Log[173] + Log[1861] - Log[68716865519])
```

Answer (score 5):

Using Solve I get the exact same result as you noted in the last sentence.

```
Solve[1000*(1.0609^t) == 1500, t]
```

Comment: Yes but when you do that, Mathematica says "Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>"